# is clearing lists before returning good?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm working with C# and in some methods I use several lists for database results. These can be quite large (10 lists of about 1,000 objects each).
For the moment, I just return from these methods and let the garbage collector clear it. If just before returning I write `TheList.Clear();` is this going to be of any benefit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since calling `Clear` on the list doesn't cause garbage collection on the data, but only removes the reference from the list to the objects, it won't give any benefit.

Answer (score 2):

No, because you are not copying the list toward who called the method, you are sending a reference toward that list that exist only at one place in memory. If you clear the list, you will clear the list you send out of the method too since it's the same.

If I give you a box, you fill it with object, but after you give me back the box, you empty it, it will be empty.

Comment: I use the 10 list to compose a list of new objects.

Comment: @frenchie: The list is an object too. A list of reference toward other object. The list doesn't take much space in memory, the object inside it do.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the garbage collector will detect there being no reference to the list or its contents regardless of whether you have done this, and memory doesn't get reclaimed until the garbage collector runs.